# Hashing a password in login form using WPF based on C#

Tags: c#, mysql, hash

I am trying to implement logIn form in WPF based on C# using MySQL. Bellow is my code. When I try to run the program everything seems fine, but when I try to fill the info I am getting error on line:

```
salt = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as string;
```

It says that: Unknown column 'salt' in 'field list' on the line. What I tried to do is to create column salt in my table. First I did not entered data and get "Wrong details", then I inserted the same data as my password and get the same error: "Wrong details". By any chance do you have any idea how can I resolve my problem?

Here is my code where the sensitive data is replaced:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Security.Util;




namespace ECBSRecruitmentAgencySoftware
{
    public partial class LogIn : Form
    {

        public LogIn()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }

    static byte[] GenerateSaltedHash(string plainText, string salt)
    {
       HashAlgorithm algorithm = new SHA256Managed();

       byte[] plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText);
       byte[] saltBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);

       byte[] plainTextWithSaltBytes = new byte[plainTextBytes.Length + saltBytes.Length];
       saltBytes.CopyTo(plainTextWithSaltBytes, 0);
       plainTextBytes.CopyTo(plainTextWithSaltBytes, salt.Length); 

       byte[] hash = algorithm.ComputeHash(plainTextWithSaltBytes);

       return hash;
    }

        public bool tryLogin(string username , string password)
        {
             using (var con = new MySqlConnection("host=tara.rdb.superhosting.bg;user=sozopouk;password=27051996;database=sozopouk_test2;"))
             {
                 con.Open();

                 var salt = string.Empty;

                 using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select salt From niki where user_name = @username", con))
                 {
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);

                     salt = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as string;
                 }

                 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(salt)) return false;

                 var hashedPassword = GenerateSaltedHash(password, salt);

                 using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * FROM niki WHERE user_name = @username and user_password = @password", con))
                 {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", hashedPassword);

                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                         return reader.Read();
                    }
                 }
             }
             }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tryLogin(user.Text, pass.Text) == true)
            {
                MainScreen F2 = new MainScreen();
                F2.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }

            else MessageBox.Show("Wrong details!");
        }
        }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the table Niki have no field names as salt.

Following code is returning NULL in `salt` variable.

```
salt = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as string;
```

So on next statement you are checking for null or empty value of salt.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(salt)) return false;
```

and you are returning false from code if salt is empty or null. So `tryLogin` function returns false and you see the unwanted message box of "Wrong details!".

You can place an message box to display value of salt returned from `ExecuteScalar()` for verification

Comment: I do not understand what I had to replace?

Comment: The value of salt is blank/null for the user, you are passing in the tryLogin() function. If you will enter some value in table for that user  in salt field. Then the code will perfectly work.

Comment: I inserted data: 12300 in the salt field in my niki table but still getting error. Any idea?

Comment: Please verify that the table has the user (passed in trylogin() function) and the salt field value against this user is filled.

Comment: that is my table structure:

table name: niki

user_id         int(5)   
user_name       varchar(255)
user_password varchar(150)
salt         varchar(256) 

Data:

1  niki   1210   1210
2 george  1220   1220

Can you see the mistake somewhere?